# Is this simple program semantically correct?

Tags: c++11, semantics

I'm a beginner in C++ (4 days or so into my course) i created a small program that seems to work the way i want it to.

Quick summary:

The program asks for your name.
then asks for two numbers to add together.
displays the answer.
then asks if you want to calculate again y/n.

However, i can't help but feel like its a total train wreck in terms of formatting.

In particular the `Again()` function...
Inside of it, i created a loop by calling on another function `if` the condition was true. like so:

```
bool Again() {

std::cout << "Would you like to calculate again y/n?\n";
std::string answer = "";
std::cin >> answer;

if (answer[0] == 'y') { 
    std::cout << "Cool lets do it then \n";
    PickTwo();
    Again();
}
else {
    std::cout << "alright, goodbye\n";
}
return 0;
}
```

Is it proper or improper to create a loop the way i did in Again() ?
if so, is there a right way to do it ?

This is the entire program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void Greetings();
int PickTwo();
bool Again();

int main() {

    Greetings();
    PickTwo();
    Again();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void Greetings() {

    std::cout << "Hi my name is Program, we're going to do something today. \n";
    std::cout << "Whats your name?\n";
    std::string Name;
    std::getline(std::cin, Name);
    std::cout << "Hi " << Name << ", we're going to try to do math\n";
    return;
}

int PickTwo() {

    std::cout << "Please pick the numbers to be added\n";
    int firstNumber;
    std::cin >> firstNumber;
    int secondNumber;
    std::cin >> secondNumber;

    int Answer = firstNumber + secondNumber;

    std::cout << "This are your numbers " << firstNumber << " and " << secondNumber << std::endl;
    std::cout << "If we add them you have " << Answer << std::endl;


    return Answer;
}

bool Again() {

    std::cout << "Would you like to calculate again y/n?\n";
    std::string answer = "";
    std::cin >> answer;

    if (answer[0] == 'y') {
        std::cout << "Cool lets do it then \n";
        PickTwo();
        Again();
    }
    else {
        std::cout << "alright, goodbye\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Thank you in advance, knowing what NOT to do will help me fix the bad habits before they get worst.

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: Is it proper or improper to create a loop the way i did in Again() ?
if so, is there a right way to do it ?

Comment: In my opinion it is incorrect, as is returning 0 when you said you would return true or false. This is a place to ask focused questions about problems, not to learn to program by asking if you're doing it right.

Comment: What you did isn't writing a loop, but a recursive program (function that calls itself). Have you already learned about loops (while/for)? Also, for code reviews you should post your code on https://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: why need return 0 ?

Comment: Ah, thank you MikeMB i will do that from now on.
I haven't really gone very far in depth with while/for, just thought i'd give it a go.

But i will do as you say and next time ask in codereview.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it proper or improper to create a loop the way i did in Again() ? if so, is there a right way to do it ?

In a language that does not support tail recursion, your program has the potential to cause stack overflow. I would not recommend using it they way you have it coded.

It will be better to use a `while` loop or a `do-while` loop. In the loop, do whatever you need to do *again*.

Comment: or use `do-while` loop

Comment: @JohnJoe, of course.